# Java XStream - Is it possible to ignore tags that are not recognized outside the Alias

Tags: java, xstream

Before you mark this question as Duplicate please read carefully. My problem is not similar to a lot of questions on SO.

I am using XStream as follows:

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias;

@XStreamAlias("square")
public class Square {
    @XStreamAlias("size")
    int size;

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Square [size=" + size + "]";
    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

}
```

For the following XML Structure:

```
<square>
    <size>12</size>
</square>
```

it works fine.

For the following XML Structure:

```
<square>
    <size>12</size>
    <width>12</width>
</square>
```

I found a solution on Stack Overflow already.

```
XStream xstream = new XStream() {
            @Override
            protected MapperWrapper wrapMapper(MapperWrapper next) {
                return new MapperWrapper(next) {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldSerializeMember(Class definedIn,
                            String fieldName) {
                        if (definedIn == Object.class) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        return super
                                .shouldSerializeMember(definedIn, fieldName);
                    }
                };
            }
        };
```

But my problem is that my webservice gets hit by the following XML structure a lot:

```
<heading>
<square>
   <size>12</size>
   <width>12</width>
</square>
```

Now my problem is that it throws CannotResolveClassException which I am catching and trying to go on with the execution but it reaches EOFException i.e. it treats it as if it finished the parsing completely. How do I make the XStream ignore the tags outside of Alias as well just like someone wrote a smart piece of code to ignore unknown elements inside the recognized alias.